# Doesnt seem to get the reference in lua, but only the value

Tags: lua, love2d, luajit

I am getting Components, which are saved in tables(I use a special system for better memory effiency). Then i give them as parameters in a given function(with the unpack statement(I already checked it isnt the reason)). So far so good, I get the value that is saved in the Table. But if I change it the component in the table doesnt change value. So in short: I want to give the component by reference but I am giving it by value. I thought Lua always gives values stored in tables by reference. Any help would be appreciated. If you need any additional resources just ask :). Thankyou in advance

```
function pool:run(dt)-- runs all active systems
local sprite = self.img
for i, method in ipairs(self.mPool) do
    if method[1] then
        --finds entities with required components
        local matches = {}
        for x=1, #self.ePool do
            if band(self.ePool[x][1], method[2]) == method[2] then
                matches[#matches+1] = x
            end
        end
        --get components of entities
        local components = {}
        for x=1, #method[3] do
            components[x] = {}
            local marker=1
            local savePosition = 1
            for Eid=1, matches[#matches] do-- Eid = entity id
                if Eid == matches[marker] then
                    components[marker][#components[marker]+1] = self.cPool[method[3][x]][savePosition]
                    marker = marker +1
                end

                if self.cBool[method[3][x]][Eid] then
                    savePosition = savePosition +1
                end
            end
        end
        --reorder and run as coroutine or function
        if method[5] then 
            for x=1, #components do
                coroutine.wrap(method[4])(matches[x], unpack(components[x]), dt)
            end
        else
            for x=1, #components do 
                method[4](matches[x], unpack(components[x]), dt)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: It gets dereferenced in line 20(should have only posted line20 as the rest is still pretty messy), so how could i pass on the reference while still staying as close as possible to my original?

Comment: Lua tables are always "passed by reference". Your question is very hard to follow. Can you make a minimal piece of code, say what you expect it to do, and what it does instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you set a variable to the value of table content the value not the reference will be set.

Comment: That is not an accurate description of how Lua works.